# Try if there is any $_GET value

Tags: php

There is a way to determine if there is any $_GET value (not with a specific key) passed in a GET request ? I'm not sure the syntax

```
isset($_GET)
```

is valide

Comment: There are a few ways, `!empty()` is another way.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` is array so use `count` instead of `isset`.

```
<?php
  if(count($_GET) >0){
   //valid
 }
?>
```